Are complex numbers considered as scalars or vectors?
I came across this definition in a linear algebra textbook:
Elements of  are called scalars. The word “scalar” (which is just a fancy
word for “number”) is often used when we want to emphasize that an object is a
number, as opposed to a vector. This confuses me because  stands for either R or C, and I thought elements in C are vector quantities, and answers on the internet vary. I know that they are definitely treated like scalars (at least in the textbook) because of this exercise:
Explain why there does not exist  ∈  such that
(2 − 3, 5 + 4, −6 + 7) = (12 − 5, 7 + 22, −32 − 9).
If it is the case that  elements in C are scalars, is there a geometric interpretation of scalar multiplication when scalars are complex numbers?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Scalars are elements of a field such as $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, but also $\mathbb C$ can be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, so it depends on the context

Only when you have determined which field you are working on you can say about scalars. For example, given a field $F$ and a vector space $V$ over $F$, one may call an element in $F$ a scalar. It is meaningless to say about scalars without pointing out a field.

In modern mathematics, the terms "scalar" and "vector" do not have fixed meanings. Rather, given a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbf{F}$, we adopt the linguistic convention of calling the elements of $V$ "vectors" and the elements of $\mathbf{F}$ "scalars". Often in beginning courses to linear algebra, we only consider real or complex vector spaces – vector spaces where $\mathbf F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbf F=\mathbb C$. But this still leaves open the possibility that, say, $\mathbf F=V=\mathbb R$, in which case the reals are playing the role of both scalars and vectors.

Ah I see. Thanks for the explanations!

Elements of sets can be both vectors and scalars depending on the context. Vectors are always elements of a vector space and scalars are always elements of the corresponding field.
Some examples:
The vector space $\mathbb{C}$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Here the vectors are in $\mathbb{C}$ and the scalars in $\mathbb{R}$.
The vector space $\mathbb{C}$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$. Here vectors and scalars both belong to $\mathbb{C}$.
The vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$. Here vectors belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and scalars belong to $\mathbb{Q}$.
